# key value pair mapping - from a dataframe to cassandra table

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra

A json parsed Dataframe (insertDF) is in the form:

```
+------------------------------------------------+-------------+------------+
Cls_details                                       | prdct_cde   |roll_nbr
+------------------------------------------------+-------------+------------+

{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2","key3":"value3"}|DKLA          |123453  
{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2","key3":"value3"}|GHTD        |123454      
{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2","key3":"value3"}|ILDDA        |123455
```

i want to save this dataframe to a cassandra table.
The spark scala code used is:

```
insertDF
      .write.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
      .options(Map("keyspace" -> "abc", "table" -> "def"))
      .mode(SaveMode.Append).save()
```

But iam getting the error:

```
com.datastax.spark.connector.types.TypeConversionException: Cannot convert object {"key1":"value1","key2":"value2","key3":"value3"} of type class java.lang.String to Map[AnyRef,AnyRef].
```

Please suggest solutions in **spark scala.**
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: you need to convert Cls_details to map type.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57044746/how-to-convert-nested-json-to-map-object-in-scala

Comment: have tried.
its not working.
Could you please  suggest code for changing schema of type struct to map.
in Cassandra the column type is  Frozen<Map<String, String>>