# Convert a scala dataframe Json string column to a map

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark

I have a dataframe structure as shown below:

```
+----+----+--------------------+
|col1|col2|col3                |
+----+----+--------------------+
|1   |2   |{"key1" : "val1"}   |
|3   |4   |{"key2" : "val2"}   |
+----+----+--------------------+
```

col3 is a *Json String*. I would like to add another column to the dataframe that will convert col3 to a MAP. Something like this:

```
+----+----+--------------------+----------------+
|col1|col2|col3                |col4            |
+----+----+--------------------+----------------+
|1   |2   |{"key1" : "val1"}   |[key1 -> val1]  |
|3   |4   |{"key2" : "val2"}   |[key2 -> val2]  |
+----+----+--------------------+----------------+
```

My Scala code snippet is something like this:

```
val df: DataFrame = getRowDataset(payload, schema, "payload") // df is represented by the first column
df.withColumn("col4", "<>") // <What do I need to do here?>
```

How am I supposed to implement this with Scala?

Comment: Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57044746/how-to-convert-nested-json-to-map-object-in-scala/57055993#57055993 related question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert nested JSON to map object in scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57044746/how-to-convert-nested-json-to-map-object-in-scala)

Comment: ```val df2 = df.withColumn("map_data", from_json((df("crawl_request")), mappingSchema))```. This works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57044746/how-to-convert-nested-json-to-map-object-in-scala/57055993#57055993) as a reference, the solution is as follows:

```
    val mappingSchema = MapType(StringType, StringType)
    val df2 = df.withColumn("col4", from_json((df("col3")), mappingSchema))
```

Note: *df("col3")* is a Json String in my use case.